# Jquery ajaxsetup: Catch only 401 error else let the custom error handler do the job

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-5, jquery-ajaxq

I have a complex application (.NET 5 MVC 5) which does various ajax calls.
I would like to globally handle only 401 unauthorized requests.

This classic code does the trick as it catches globally

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 401) {//Unauthorized
            //it will redirect to the same document, so authentication will take place and will go back to login
            window.location.href = document.URL;
        }
    }
});
```

But it catches globally everything while I need it to catch only 401 and let the defined error function do the rest.

What I mean is, for example I have:

```
function dropYear_changed(data) {
    $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("aaa", "vvv")',
     type: "get",
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            //Do stuff
     },
     error: function(error) {
     //show some alert, toast, do error stuff
     }
 });
}
```

with the global ajax it won't do the

```
//show some alert, toast, do error stuff
```

because the ajaxSetup will take over.
I want to catch 401 globally but do something else if error is not 401, and that something else is defined in the ajax error:

How I can do this?

Comment: See https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2228-some-thoughts-on-handling-401-unauthorized-errors-with-jquery.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch only specific errors in **$.ajaxSetup** with **statusCode** function. Try below code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            alert("401");
        }
    }
});
```

This function alert when the response status is a 401. This way you can catch 401 globally and do something else if error is not 401.

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much!!!!! I will let you know shortly